# Javascript: Altering Textbox 'Type' on click

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, textbox

I have a part of my site where users login, and I'd like to have the textboxes populate with default values, but obviously the password textbox needs to change to type="password" on a user click to hide the characters. A great example of this IMO is on Apple's www.me.com website. Any help on the best way to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to show a control with the default value in it...then then the user enters the control, hide it and show the actual password control at that point.  When the user leaves the password control, if she hasn't actually entered a value, or has deleted the existing value, at that time re-show the first control and hide the password control.  Here is example code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="ecmascript">
        function HandlePasswordOnFocus() {
            if ("none" != TheForm.a.style.display) {

                TheForm.a.style.display = "none";
                TheForm.b.style.display = "block";
                TheForm.b.focus();
            }
        }
        function HandlePasswordOnBlur() {
            if ("" === TheForm.b.value) {
                TheForm.b.style.display = "none"
                TheForm.a.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="TheForm">
    <input id="a" value="password" onfocus="HandlePasswordOnFocus()" />
    <input id="b" type="password" style="display: none" onblur="HandlePasswordOnBlur()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your idea of changing the type would work on *most* browsers. However, old versions of IE do not allow you to dynamically modify the type of an input control, making for a complex node replacement that could lose information in the process. Rather, you should use the new HTML5 `placeholder` property which does not work in every browser but is more obvious and leaner than the script you would need to perform this replacements. It's easy to use:

```
<input type="password" name="pwd" value="" placeholder="Enter your password." />
```

It's compatible with Firefox 3.7 or higher, Chrome and Safari 4 or higher, and IE9 or higher.

Comment: Excellent. That should work, what will happen on non-HTML5 browsers?

Comment: @Zakman411: The placeholder text simply won't display. Nothing will break. It degrades gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to change the type, you could simply use a javascript function to change it when the user clicks the textbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeType() {
    document.getElementById("password").type = "password";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "";
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="Password" onClick="changeType()" />
```

But, as other posters have suggested - consider using the placeholder property.

Comment: Fails miserably in IE (as in usually breaks the rest of the script) though, so be warned...

Answer (score 1):

example: http://jsfiddle.net/n3SPH/

```
<label for="placeholder">Password:</label>
<input type="text" id="placeholder" value="Enter password here" onFocus="setPass();"/>
<input type="password" id="password" value="" onBlur="checkPass();" style="display: none;"/>
```

JS:

```
function setPass() {
    document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('password').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('password').focus();
}
function checkPass() {
    if (document.getElementById('password').value.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('placeholder').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('password').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked but broke the form : / id's are all checked and same as before, but now pressing Login does nothing...any ideas on why?

Comment: @Zakman411: Remember that this example code does not name the input controls - add the appropriate `name` attribute. (Of course, if the form actually shows no signs of submission then that's not your problem...)

Answer (score 1):

The way Apple is doing it at Me.com is they set the input field to be transparent and then have a DIV behind it with the text they want to display. When someone starts typing in the field they hide that label div that's behind it.

If you don't want to use `placeholder=""` like others have suggested (I'm not sure why Apple didn't just do that since Safari supports it?), another way to do it is to have an image load as a background for that field, with the placeholder text you want, and then give it a class with a `background:none` CSS property when someone starts typing. That would require less extra mark-up (but more tinkering in Photoshop...).